# PHP Regex Key phrase matching

Tags: php, regex, keyword, phrase

I have a text field where the user will enter comma separated keywords or key phrases, and the server will then use these values to check multiple bodies of text for matches.

So basically what I need is to match an exact phrase, case insensitive, with possible spaces in a body of text.

I can match keywords easily, by generating the following regex:

**Example keywords**: `peanut, butter, jelly`

**Regex generated**: `/peanut|butter|jelly/i`

However having spaces does not work. Even if I replace the spaces in the given values with `\s`

**Example**: `peanut butter, jelly sandwich, delicious`

**Regex**: `/peanut\sbutter|jelly\ssandwich|delicious/i`

What would be a correct regex to match the phrases exactly ? Case insensitive and using PHP's  `preg_match` ?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is what I am doing:

```
$keywordsArray = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $keywords ) );
$keywordsArrayEscaped = array_map( 'preg_quote', $keywordsArray );
$keywordsRegex = '/' . implode( '|', $keywordsArrayEscaped ) . '/i';
```

The above generates the expressions as described above ( Without the replacement of spaces to `\s`, since it didn't work. )

Following that I simple do `preg_match( $keywordsRegex, $text );`

Comment: I don't see thee issue. Spaces work for in preg_match for me. Provide some code.

Comment: where are the target text you're trying to check come from? are they encoded like `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Would `$keywords = explode(", ", $in);` not be easier?

Comment: show us your code. impossible to help unless you do, because we don't know what's actually going on in your specific situation. `preg_match` can handle both spaces and `\s` just fine, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Yea, but I am walking the array and trimming the values. So it's pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Put it into parenthesises instead `/(peanut buffer|jelly sandwich|delicious)/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why it wouldn't work with spaces or **\s**. It should. But to answer the question you asked in general terms, the way to match exact phrases in a regex is to surround them with **\Q** and **\E**:

```
/\Q<phrase 1>\E|\Q<phrase 2>\E|\Q<phrase 3>\E/
```

That's normally used for text that contains escapes or regex metacharacters. You really shouldn't need that for spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I could really find with your code is that you aren't filling in the third field for the results;

```
preg_match($keywordsRegex, $text, $results);

var_dump($results);
```

Comment: Because I'm only concerned with whether or not it matched.